# Coimage and Image bijective

Tags: category-theory

In a pre-abelian category, it is known that the coimage and image of a morphism (if they exist) need not be isomorphic.  Is there necessarily a bijection between them?  For example, the the category of topological abelian groups, one can show that the canonical morphism $\varphi:\mathrm{coim}~f \to \mathrm{im}~f$ is identified with $f:X \to Y$ if $f$ is bijective.  It's easy to cook up an example where this is not an isomorphism, but we already have a bijection.

If there is a bijection, it should be $\varphi$; but I'm having trouble playing around with the arrows without thinking of maps and sets.  I don't see any reason why it should be a bijection, but I'm not too familiar with the exotic examples.

Comment: Bijection doesn't make sense in the general setting of a pre-abelian category, you need it to also be a concrete category. You can talk about a morphism being a bimorphism, which is a morphism that is both mono- and epi-. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I guess I was being sloppy with notation.  I wanted something that mirrors bijection, where it makes sense.  So of course mono and epi.

Comment: @BenjaminTighe This is not a trivial change from your original question! Note that the example in my answer *is* a mono-epi, despite not being a bijection of sets.

Comment: I made an edit to my question.  I was being too specific because I didn't know how general I wanted the answer to be.

Answer (score 5):

This is not true.

Let me first make a slightly pedantic point: the question doesn't make sense since there are pre-abelian (even abelian) categories which are not concretizable, and so we can't make sense of "bijection."

But even in the concrete case, the underlying sets need not be in bijection. In the very example you cite (topological abelian groups*), take the inclusion $\mathbb{Q} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (under addition, giving $\mathbb{Q}$ the subspace topology). The coimage is $\mathbb{Q}$ and the image is $\mathbb{R}$ (indeed, the map is the original inclusion, just as you mention), which are not in bijection.

*This should be *Hausdorff* TAGs -- thanks Arnaud D. for catching this.

Comment: I was thinking of this example, but I didn't think $\mathbb R$ was the image intuitively.  Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Are you sure that the image is $\mathbb{R}$ in the category of topological abelian groups? That doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: Since $\Bbb Q\to\Bbb R$ is epic, its cokernel is $\Bbb R\to 0$, and the kernel of that is $id:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{R}$ is not an epimorphism in the category of topological abelian groups; in fact one can show that in the category of topological abelian groups kernels and cokernels are computed as in the category of sets and endowed with subspace or quotient topology. So the induced map between image and coimage is always bijective. For this example to work, you need to consider *Hausdorff* abelian groups.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Thanks! I tend to think of my topological groups as being $T_1$ (and thus Hausdorff), but that definitely isn't what I should mean by the category of such. Editing now.